# For a given permutation t, does there exist n-cycle s such that $t=s^{k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

If $$t=(1\; 2)(3\; 4)(5\; 6)(7\; 8)(9\; 10),$$ question is asking determine whether there is a $n$-cycle $s$ ($n \geq10$) with $t=s^{k}$ for some integer $k$? Can someone provide me start to tackle this one.

Comment: What is $s$ here?

Comment: s is any n-cycle..n cycle means permutation with only one cycle having n elements like (1 2 3) is 3-cycle

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: And is $n$ fixed? And is $s$ a number or a permutation?

Comment: @Parcly Taxel Sorry I am unable to start the problem. Exactly what logic I should use, I am not getting. That's why I just want a start. Any hint please.

Comment: s is permutation ( actually I wanted to use standard notation like sigma and tou, but I don't know their latex notation at the moment) and n is any number.

Comment: `$\sigma$` and `$\tau$`

Comment: Hint. Why don't you take a random $10$-cycle, say $$s=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10),$$ and compute $s^2$, $s^3$, $s^4$, $s^5$, etc., and see if one of them looks sort of like $(1\ 2)(3\ 4)(5\ 6)(7\ 8)(9\ 10)$? And then maybe you can fiddle with the numbers and make it look exactly like $(1\ 2)(3\ 4)(5\ 6)(7\ 8)(9\ 10)$?

Comment: @bof and Christoph Thank you.  Somehow, I've always thought that a power of a cycle is a cycle, but it's clearly false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\lcm{lcm}$If you raise an $n$-cycle to the $k$-th power, you will get $\gcd(n,k)$ cycles of length $\frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$. The permutation $\tau=(1\ 2)(3\ 4)(5\ 6)(7\ 8)(9\ 10)$ consists of $5$ $2$-cycles, which can be achieved by letting $n=10$ and $k=5$. Indeed
$$
\tau = (1\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 9\ 2\ 4\ 6\ 8\ 10)^5.
$$

Here are two other examples to get a better understanding of the general phenomenon:
\begin{align}
(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 11\ 12\ 13\ 14\ 15)^6
&= (1\ 7\ 13\ 4\ 10)(2\ 8\ 14\ 5\ 11)(3\ 9\ 15\ 6\ 12),\\
(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^{15}
&= (1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)^3 = (1\ 4)(2\ 5)(3\ 6).
\end{align}

Comment: thanks for the result. The next question was asking the same thing as this question, but there t=(1 2)(3 4 5). So by your result there won't be any n-cycle s such that t=$s^{k}$ as n-cycle raised to power k is always a permutation having cycles of equal length. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is also obvious from symmetry reasons, since in an $n$-cycle all cycled elements behave in the same way (you can conjugate to swap their roles, while in a product of a 2- and a 3-cycle this symmetry is broken